# Is it possible to execute a ruby script as a pre-build step?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, hudson

I want to execute a ruby script for all of my projects on Jenkins. Whenever I try to add a ruby script at a pre-build step it fails the build and returns with following error:

```
[workspace] $ ruby -v /tmp/hudson4496135006077199221.rb
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
/tmp/hudson4496135006077199221.rb:1: unterminated regexp meets end of file
Build step 'Execute Ruby script' marked build as failure
```

For now ruby script just has one `print` statement and nothing else.

Whereas if I put the ruby code in the space provided it runs just fine.

It will be cumbersome to paste the ruby script on all the projects which is not desirable.

Please let me know if there is a way to add Ruby Script file.

Update: 
Contents of the file:`puts "Hello"`

Command used in the Jenkins pre-build step: `ruby ~/.sample.rb`

Thanks

Comment: show us the contents of the file.

Comment: @Anthony File just has `puts "Hello"`

Answer (score 1):

After researching a bit, it's not possible to specify the path of Ruby Script.
Instead I wrote a Rake Task and specified the path of Rakefile.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are doing this? Are you using the Hudson Ruby Plugin and calling the Rakefile from there? (and if so how exactly, e.g. with bundler?)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute any kind of script. You can write your commands as if you where in the terminal, there is no apparent reason why that shouldn't work.

What is probably happening is that the file you're trying to execute is not there. Can it be that instead of `ruby ~/.sample.rb` you have to write `ruby ~/sample.rb`? If it is not that try to debug it. You could put `ls` just before `ruby ~/.sample.rb` to see where is jenkins trying to execute your code.

Comment: I know that we can write any kind of script that needs to be executed in that box. The reason why I feel that we're not able to specify the path of file is whatever you write in that file is compiled into one temporary file and Jenkins executes it as ruby script. For example: `ruby ~/.sample.rb` is compiled into `[workspace] $ ruby -v /tmp/hudson1715556226240775423.rb` Jenkins try to execute these set of lines as a Ruby commands which it is not. Instead I feel jenkins should be able to determine which is script file and which is actual script.